# Is there a USB-C/DP to DisplayPort converter that can maintain the original framerate (and resolution) of USB-C/PD?

Tags: displayport, adapter, usb-c, framerate, high-resolution

I have a monitor with a large screen (3440x1440) supporting 144 Hz, that only has DisplayPort and HDMI ports.

I also have a laptop supporting USB-C/DP.

How can I connect those two without losing framerate or resolution?
I see that there are cable converters, but they seem to limit the framerate and/or resolution.

(I am guessing that my graphics card can handle this, but I am not even sure how to even begin to check this...)

Comment: Without us knowing what the graphics card is, we can't even begin to guess either... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. However, these adapters are *extremely* rare.

You can easily get adapters that carry two DP lanes. This isn’t enough on DisplayPort versions up to and including 1.4. It would be enough on DP 2.0, but that’s still too new.

On DP 1.4, you need three (maybe four) lanes for uncompressed 3440×1440@144.

Why do most adapters only carry two DP lanes? Because of USB 3.x. It needs all the other wires. However, USB-C is flexible. It can be configured to only use USB 2.0, freeing up enough wires for four DP lanes. Unfortunately, I’m not aware of any such adapter that also supports (according to the datasheet) DisplayPort 1.4. I only know the StarTech DK30C2DAGPD, which lists 4k60 as the maximum resolution, which requires a lot less bandwidth. It could work anyway, so maybe give it a try.

Of course, your laptop must also support DisplayPort 1.4. Note that the GPU supporting DP 1.4 is not enough. I had a laptop which used a USB-C connectivity chip that only supported DP 1.2, even though the iGPU could do DP 1.4.

Please also note that Thunderbolt works in an entirely different way. If your laptop supports Thunderbolt, a Thunderbolt docking station could also be a solution. Its DisplayPort capabilities must be closely scrutinized however.

Comment: 4:2:0 YUV mode might help get the refresh rate a little higher if OP is willing to compromise on text sharpness. What about DSC? Might also help squeeze some more refresh rate out of a DP 1.4 connection if both ends support it.

Comment: @Romen Yes, those certainly are ways. Support varies, however.